# Better time representation with Gantt chart (pgfgantt)

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

Pretty new to pgfgantt. Can anyone tell me how I can represent time with an $x$-axis , up the top of down the bottom of the chart?

MWE:

[image: gantt_pic]

```
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\OG}{\color{OliveGreen}}
\newcommand{\vio}{\color{Violet}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{ganttchart}[inline, x unit = 1cm]{0}{12}
        \gantttitle{Time}{13}\\
        \gantttitlelist{0,...,12}{1} \\
        \ganttbar[inline=false]{\LG $M_1$}{1}{1}
        \ganttbar{\vio $J_3$}{0}{1}
        \ganttbar{\vio $J_4$}{3}{5}
        \ganttbar{\vio $J_2$}{6}{9}
        \ganttbar{\vio $J_1$}{10}{11}
        \end{ganttchart}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, i would like it more like this tikz picture:

[image: tikz_pic]

But with the x-ticks as well.

Thanks everyone!